# Crashes app in background when adding annotation on MKMapView

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapview

After adding annotation and if user put app in background, after 1 second it crashes. In foreground it is not crashing. It does not show in logs about crash.

Adding a annotation from viewDidLoad() method

```
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat as! Double, longitude: long as! Double)
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Delegate method code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let pin = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    pin.canShowCallout = true
    let button = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
    pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button
    return pin
}
```

Crash log:

[image: crash logs]

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

**UPDATE**

Even after created a new project with simply adding an annotation in MKMapView. It behaves the same as mine. Is it global framework issue? Any other guys faced/facing?

Please Help!

Comment: You need to get the exception message. Perhaps set an exception breakpoint.

Comment: @Paulw11 I put all exceptional breakpoint but nothing works. Also I tried to create new project with MKMapview and adding annotation that is project is also crashed in same way.

Comment: What is `lat` and `Lon`? What values do they have and how are they set?  Have you set your map to display the user's location?

Comment: @Paulw11 Its Double value. Correctly plotted a point on map. And yes just to let you know I get error [MTLDebugTexture removeUsedRenderTarget:slices:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fc130e18210 by enabling NSZombieEnabled. Any idea?

Comment: Are you testing on the simulator or a device?

Comment: @Paulw11 Both crashes

Comment: Have you set the map to show the user's location?

Comment: @Paulw11 its fixed by just disabling Metal API validation in scheme diagnostic :) By the way thanks for continuous support.

Comment: It's by default setting enabled when project created.

Answer (score 0):

Using expressions like `lat as! Double` is almost always a bad idea.

Try something like `if let lat = lat as? Double` and make a nice error handling if that fails.